# Pandas automatically changing to column value to datetime

Tags: python, excel, pandas

When I read a excel file `df = pd.read_excel(file, header=none)` it automatically converts a date column in excel file `01/04/2020 TO 01-04-2020 00:00:00:00` but I want it to stay as `01/04/2020` itself. The issue is that the date column name in excel might be changing for different excels. So that I can't do something like `df[that column name].change_to_str_date_%d-%m-%y`.

Is there a way for this conversion not to happen?
Or is there a way to find all datetime columns and convert it to date only format ?

Comment: `df[that column name] = df[that column name].dt.strftime('%d/%m%Y')` before saving to excel.

Comment: But as I said in question. I dont know the column heading of that column. It keeping changing from excel to excel

Comment: @QuangHoang is there a way to find column name ? Or is there a way to change all column with dtype as datetime?

Comment: Yes: `for col in df.columns: if df[col].dtype == 'datetime64[ns]': do_something`